# VS 2017 15.8 update broke Publish Selected Files

Tags: visual-studio

I can no longer publish selected files in Visual Studio after upgrading to VS 2017 15.8 .  The keyboard shortcut Alt + ; then Alt + P  gives an error and the if I right click on file in the Solution Explorer it no longer shows an option in the Context menu for "Publish [filename]"

The error message from the keyboard shortcut is "The key combination (Alt+;, Alt+P) is bound to command (Publish selected files) which is not currently available .

Any workaround?

Comment: Have you searched on the official forum and release notes?

Comment: @S4NNY1 release notes don't mention this.

Comment: Seems to be an issue when you are using the File System Publishing profile which we are.  If you choose any other type of publishing profile the item gets added back to the context menu.  MS has an official response to the problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311038/publish-single-file-context-menu-item-missing.html

Comment: Here is the official problem report from MS on this issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311038/publish-single-file-context-menu-item-missing.html

Comment: A new version of visual studio has been released to address this issue. 15.8.2

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017 v 15.8.4 and I still see this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 15.8.2, which I installed yesterday, comes with a fix. The shortcut should work again for everyone.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?!
This update fixed the problem for me, any updates before DID NOT.

Answer (score 0):

> This bug was found back in April 2017 in **Visual Studio 2017 15.1** and was fixed in **15.3**. I believe they will fix this again in upcoming updates.

Partial workaround found on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/0b8c9e8f5ca628a1c5c4c7f0b7becaf51624942f/README.md): 
**Sample to skip specific folders and files during Web Deploy Publish**

```
<ItemGroup>

    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder1">
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>wwwroot</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>

    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder2">
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>wwwroot\\Content$</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>

    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile1">
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>Views\\Home\\About.cshtml</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>

    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile2">
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>Views\\Home\\About2.cshtml</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>

</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: How should that help?

Comment: @WhoMightThisOneBe you can simply create profiles and SkipRules for them, so for example you will publish only on file with first profile and all the others in second..